# DesignInstance in XAML with VS2017 not showing data at design time

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I struggle creating the necessary data at design time of a UWP application in VS2017. I created a simple project to work on my issue here. 
What is wrong with my DesignInstance DataContext in this case? 
VS 2017 doesn't show anything during design time - when I add a "real" data context in page.resources it shows data.

### View

```
    <Page
    x:Class="SpeedboatExplorer.Views.WelcomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SpeedboatExplorer.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:SpeedboatExplorer.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MockWelcomeViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Input}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

### MockViewModel

```
namespace SpeedboatExplorer.ViewModels
{
    public  class MockWelcomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _title;
        private string _input;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
            }
        }

        public string Input
        {
            get => _input;
            set
            {
                _input = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Input));
            }
        }

        public MockWelcomeViewModel()
        {
            _title = "Welcome Page";
            _input = "input text";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your app target version 16299? I can reproduce it on app witch target on 16299, but it works if I change the target version 15063. I have report it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/174281/uwp-app-target-16299-designinstance-in-xaml-with-v.html#), now you can try to target your app on 15063 to make the data display on design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the blog post [A significant update to the XAML Designer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/09/11/a-significant-update-to-the-xaml-designer/) **Feature Impact** part, you can see that XAML designer does not support the Sample data but designer instance is supported. See the blog to learn more about the update of XAML Designer.

For the issue of designer instance, you can pay attention to this feedback [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/174281/uwp-app-target-16299-designinstance-in-xaml-with-v.html?childToView=174383#comment-174383) and give your idea. If there is functionality that is important to you, you can also feedback it.